# How can I learn Cantonese in Guangdong?

Tags: study, china, language, language-course

I'm looking for a way to learn Cantonese in Guangdong.

But I have not been able to find a language school offered by universities that teach Cantonese, although that is common for Mandarin.

The only language programs I found that teaches Cantonese in China are in Hong Kong. But I prefer the one in Guangdong (Guangzhou is the best, but I'm fine with either Dongguan or Shenzhen as well).

Except for attending a language program, it is very difficult to self-study Cantonese since its learning resources are very scarce.

So, is there any university that offers Cantonese language program? Or is there any public or private language courses ([such as the French one in Paris](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/3214/good-public-school-to-learn-french-in-paris))?

Comment: You might also try asking on the [Chinese Language StackExchange](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/)